# Changed indentation settings - how to reformat old code?

Tags: indentation, whitespace

I changed my Emacs configuration including indentation settings -now when I open an old C++ file I can write code and it looks like this:

```
int x(int z){
    return z;
}
```

However, the old code in this file looks like this:

```
int x(int z){
        return z;
}
```

In other words its indentation is doubled. **How can I reformat the old code so that it's appropriately indented?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: 
  C-x h and then TAB

It changes formatting for whole buffer.

## Details

- **C-x h** - marks whole buffer
- **TAB** - indent marked region

So, effectively we mark all, then indent ;-)

Comment: Could you please edit your post to describe what command `C-x h TAB` runs, and how it resolves OP's problem?  It's for the benefit of future readers who may have the same problem.

Comment: `C-x h` marks whole buffer and TAB runs `c-indent-line-or-region` for me.